# return highest value of a variable(Xcode)

Tags: objective-c

Objective C / Xcode

I have a variable 'consecutive wins', which I need to use elsewhere for 'highest # of consecutive wins'. So I need to take the highest value of variable 'consecutive wins and only update when a higher yet value comes in.

The variable that I'm using is an 'int'

Is there a highest value of 'variable name' ?

UPDATE:

For what it's worth to others:

I made a 'consecutive wins' and a 'highest # of consecutive wins', everytime my 'if' conditions are met these are set to be equal:

if (conswins > highestconswins) {highestconswins = conswins};

Comment: welcome to [so]!  this question doesn't have enough useful detail.  Like what kind of "variable" are you talking about (an array of ints, an array of strings, or something else)?  Also, you should use the correct tags on your question -- that is, your problem is not with Xcode (the development environment) but with doing something in Objective-C.

Comment: Please share all relevant code so we can actually help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable like `consecutiveWins` can only have one value at a time. If you want to determine the largest value, you'll need to store the values over time in an array or other container. For example, every time the value changes you could first save the old value in an array.

If you're only interested in the maximum consecutive wins, then you don't necessarily need to store all the previous values. You could use a second variable, `maxConsecutiveWins` or some such, and update that whenever `consecutiveWins` gets a new value that's higher than the current `maxConsecutiveWins`.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the same thing that you're mentioned last - using another variable.